# Is it possible to define new data types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, types

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) says there are nine data types in latest JS spec. I wondering if these are the only nine data types that the spec allows programmers to use.

Just to clarify, I think programmer-defined functions/constructors internally using prototypical inheritance are still `Object`s, so do not qualify as new data types.

Comment: What do you have in mind? What's the rest of the question?

Comment: No, you cannot make your own `double` or `long` or anything else. The data types you have are all there is. The only way to get new ones is to 1. write a proposal for a new one and get it approved 2. write your own interpreter and engine that does whatever you want.

Comment: Your question is not clear: 1.- "I wondering if these are the only nine data types that the spec allows programmers to use." You mean there could be more? What is your suggestion? 2.- Functions are still objects, so should not be considered as a different type. Then we should have 8 types instead of 9. What is the point you would like to make in your question?

Comment: @JeremyThille There is no "rest" of my question. I was interested in JavaScript's type system, and just wondered if it is possible to create a new data type and then values of that type.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I agree the referenced MDN page is a bit messy, and that Function can be categorized as special objects with a `[[call]]` internal property. I was just curious if it is possible to create new data types.

Comment: "I wondering if these are the only <s>nine</s> eight data types that the spec allows programmers to use" - yes. https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types

Comment: You'll want to have a look at https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple and the discussions about *value types*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no facility that allows defining custom core data types in JavaScript. You can only use them and objects to construct what you want.